# Error when I would save two attachments in same folder in Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently developing an application to make requests. These requests can be accompanied by two attachments. These are not mandatory, there can be none, one or two.

If there are any, they will be saved in a specific folder on the Drive. This folder is a child folder created automatically and named after the id of the request.

With help of Tanaike, we try to solve that with async function but I have an error when i try this. I would like to add the id's folder to catch him and save it in my Sheets but it's doesn't work so I came back.

This is the error :

VM8304:281 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'url' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
at getFiles (:281:13)

The line 281 is "const { url } = await getResponse(files[i].f).catch(err => console.log(err));"

Here's my Html's code :

```
  <div class="form-row divHtml" id="divPhotos">
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="photoPres" class="txtPhoto"><b>Photo de près :</b></label><br>
      <input type="file" id="photoPres">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="photoLoin" class="txtPhoto"><b>Photo de loin :</b></label><br>
      <input type="file" id="photoLoin">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row divHtml">
    <div class="form-group col-8">
      <input type="button" id = "btnFichiers" value="IMPORTER LES PHOTOS" onclick="getFiles()">
      <p id="idPhotoPres"></p>
      <p id="idPhotoLoin"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's my JS's code with Tanaike's functions :

```
async function getFiles() {
   const f1 = document.getElementById('photoPres');
   const f2 = document.getElementById('photoLoin');
   const files = [{ f: f1.files[0], disp: "idPhotoPres" }, { f: f2.files[0], disp: "idPhotoLoin" }];
   for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
     if (!files[i].f) continue;
     const { url } = await getResponse(files[i].f).catch(err => console.log(err));
     document.getElementById(files[i].disp).innerHTML = url;
   }
 }

 function getResponse(file) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const fr = new FileReader();
     fr.onload = e => {
       const data = e.target.result.split(",");
       const obj = { fileName: file.name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1] };
       google.script.run.withFailureHandler(reject).withSuccessHandler(resolve).saveFile(obj);
     }
     if (file) {
       fr.readAsDataURL(file);
     } else {
       reject("No file");
     }
   });
 }
```

And here's my apps script's code :

```
function saveFile(obj){
   var pieceJointe = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
   const dossierDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById('1KRwd79dc8k8EArwHU_1RnkDHd-Sdv0DJ');

   const idDemande = generateId().toString();
   var dossierPieceJointe;
   var idDosssier = folderExists(idDemande);
   if (idDosssier !== false) { 
     dossierPieceJointe = DriveApp.getFolderById(idDosssier);
     const pieceJointeAjoutee = dossierPieceJointe.createFile(pieceJointe);
     const informationsPJ = {
       'url' : pieceJointeAjoutee.getUrl(),
     };
     return informationsPJ;
   } else {
     dossierPieceJointe = dossierDrive.createFolder(idDemande);
     const pieceJointeAjoutee = dossierPieceJointe.createFile(pieceJointe);
     const informationsPJ = {
       'url' : pieceJointeAjoutee.getUrl(),
     };
     return informationsPJ;
   }
}
 function generateId(){
   const classeur =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const webAppSheet = classeur.getSheetByName("Demandes");
   var lastRow = webAppSheet.getLastRow();
   var splitId = []; var id; var lastDemande = "";

   if(lastRow == 1){
     return (new Date().getFullYear()) + "_1";
   }else{
     lastDemande = webAppSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
     splitId = lastDemande.split('_');
     if (splitId[0] == new Date().getFullYear()){
       id = lastId + 1;
       feuilleBDD.getRange("I2").setValue(id);
       return (new Date().getFullYear()) + "_" + id;
     }
     else {
       feuilleBDD.getRange("I2").setValue(1)
       return (new Date().getFullYear()) + "_1";
     }
   }
 }

 function folderExists(nomDossierPJ) {
   const dossierDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById('1KRwd79dc8k8EArwHU_1RnkDHd-Sdv0DJ');
   var folders = dossierDrive.getFolders();
   var theReturn = false,folderName = "",folder;  
   while (folders.hasNext()) {
     folder = folders.next();
     folderName = folder.getName();

     if (folderName === nomDossierPJ) {
       theReturn = folder.getId();
       break;
     };
   };
   return theReturn;
 }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: When I saw your showing script, it seems that you are using Google Apps Script as Javascript. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: I don't think this is because I use Google Apps Script. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Here's my JS's code with Tanaike's functions :`, I thought that in your showing script, `generateId()` and `folderExists(nomDossierPJ)` include the methods of Google Apps Script. So, in this case, I thought that those are required to be included in `And here's my apps script's code :`.

Comment: Of course, my bad. I edited this. Sorry for that

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your updated scripts, no error occurs. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your current issue. I apologize for this. So, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to try to replicate it.

Comment: I apologize for that but now, it's work perfectly... I work in dev mode since the beginning, so I don't know why it's work now and no before....